# Concatenate elements in rdd list python spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have RDD as below,

```
>>> rdd.collect()
[([u'steve'], [u'new', u'york'], [u'baseball']), ([u'smith'], [u'virginia'], [u'football'])]
```

How can i get new RDD as,

```
[([u'steve'], [u'newyork'], [u'baseball']), ([u'smith'], [u'virginia'], [u'football'])]
```

i tried it to map to new rdd with JOIN but it doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix this,

```
>>> rdd2=rdd.map(lambda l: [''.join(x) for x in l])
>>> rdd2.map(tuple).collect()
[([u'steve'], [u'newyork'], [u'baseball']), ([u'smith'], [u'virginia'], [u'football'])]
```